# HTML and JSP - How to initiate an action on a form without moving to another page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an YouTube website, and everything has already been setup EXCEPT voting up and down.

Is there a way in HTML to create a upvote and a downvote button without changing the current webpage (for example a user is currently watching a video), and initiate a piece of code or a servlet that can perform some logic?

Thanks all, I'm very inexperienced with html, so I'm confused with this step.

Comment: You'd do it the same way in JSP as you would in HTML.  I.E. This has ***nothing*** to do with Java.  Removing tag.

Comment: you mean that you need an upvote downnvote without refreshing the page .....just like the upvote that you can see in stackoverflow

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan: Yeah, exactly like upvote in stackoverflow

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Sorry! I thought I could write some java code between <% %> so do this logic. I'm VERY BAD with Html and have no understanding of Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing this using HTML only. You need to save the data in database but to do that you need to do Jquery magic to post data in some webservice and save in database.

```
[Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/ukrs7/12/][1]
```

You can see the Upvote downvote JQuery logic in above fiddle,

You need to enhance this with saving in database.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I do have a RDS available, but I have no idea how to implement this.

Comment: For this you need some programing language using which you can create webservices. Then host them on Webserver and then call them.

Comment: I have a webserver and a website already setup. Where should the demo code be placed in a html? Between <html> </html>?

Comment: So I got the java script working, but not the css, can you tell me where the css should be in? I called it "background-color.css" and placed it together with the JSP file. BUT I'm not getting any colors?

Comment: .post-votes{
    width: 39px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    height:20px;
    padding:4px 3px 21px 6px;
    color:white;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color:#33E;
}

.post-upvote, .post-downvote{
    margin-left:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    height:32px;
    font-size: 200%;
    width:32px;
    
}

.post-upvote{
    color:green;
}

.post-downvote{
    color:red;
}

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by running some JavaScript on the button click events which sends an AJAX call to the server.

Google around for some exampes of AJAX calls, it's not very difficult to do. You will need to write some server-side code to handle to up/down vote requests but the fact that the requests were sent via AJAX rather than by submitting a form on the page doesn't make much difference.